# What does 'has a SUC' mean?

Tags: .net, comments, clr, .net-4.8

I was reading some .NET Code and I found the following in [DispatcherSynchronizationContext](https://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherSynchronizationContext@cs/1407647/DispatcherSynchronizationContext@cs)

```cs
/// 
///     Wait for a set of handles.
/// 
///  
///     Critical - Calls WaitForMultipleObjectsEx which has a SUC.
///  
[SecurityCritical] 
[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlPolicy|SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlEvidence)]
public override int Wait(IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout) 
{
    if(_dispatcher._disableProcessingCount > 0)
    {
        // Call into native code directly in order to avoid the default 
        // CLR locking behavior which pumps messages under contention.
        // Even though they try to pump only the COM messages, any 
        // messages that have been SENT to the window are also 
        // dispatched.  This can lead to unpredictable reentrancy.
        return MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(waitHandles.Length, waitHandles, waitAll, millisecondsTimeout, false); 
    }
    else
    {
        return SynchronizationContext.WaitHelper(waitHandles, waitAll, millisecondsTimeout); 
    }
}
```

What does "has a SUC" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to stand for the `SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity` attribute. See [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Shared/MS/Win32/UnsafeNativeMethodsOther.cs,284) for `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx`

```cs
///<SecurityNote>
/// Critical as this code performs an elevation.
///</SecurityNote>
[SecurityCritical]
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[DllImport(ExternDll.Kernel32, EntryPoint="WaitForMultipleObjectsEx", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int IntWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(int nCount, IntPtr[] pHandles, bool bWaitAll, int dwMilliseconds, bool bAlertable);
```